# Results are not displaying after changing URL with .htacess file

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, url

I have changed my following url

[http://example.com/oursitename/New-York-Mills.php?ff_nm_from[]=New+York+Mills&search=tamarind&searchval=Restaurants&location=sec&submit=GO](http://example.com/oursitename/New-York-Mills.php?ff_nm_from%5b%5d=New+York+Mills&search=tamarind&searchval=Restaurants&location=sec&submit=GO)

to

http://example.com/oursitename/New-York-Mills/New+York+Mills%252C+MN%252C+United+States/tamarind/%250D%250ARestaurants/New+york

via htaccess. But now my results are not getting displayed, also css is not there. Only HTML is there. How can I get the same results after changing the url by htaccess

Comment: Show your .htaccess code.

Comment: Please, don't use spaces in your url, use `-` instead.

Answer (score 0):

With the supplied information i can only guess ... but the problem with be that the path that you give to the html is treated as some kind of a controller. You could add this to your rewrite conditions in the htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
```